# Using seaborn's choose_colorbrewer_palette()

Tags: python, seaborn, colorbrewer

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I'm trying to use seaborn's choose_colorbrewer_palette() method. From a jupyter notebook, `sns.choose_colorbrewer_palette()` brings up the interactive tool that you can select color schemes with, but I can't figure out how to save the color scheme and actually use it in a graph. Any help? Thanks a lot!

Danny

Answer (score 1):

The [`sns.choose_colorbrewer_palette()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.choose_colorbrewer_palette.html#seaborn.choose_colorbrewer_palette) returns the the colorscheme you want to use. Depending on whether the `as_cmap` argument is true or false it will either return a list of colors ("seaborn palette") or a matplotlib colormap.

[image]

Comment: When I enter the line 'cmap = sns.choose...', the interactive map just reverts to its default value and cmap isn't defined as what I'd selected. Any idea why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: You need to first run the cell where you select the colormap and afterwards this colormap can be used.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you very much! For anyone following, DONT run the cell with cmap = ... after selecting your color. Thanks!

Comment: You can also use "s" for 'sequential' and "d" for 'diverging' color.